# Run Shoes clone in IronRuby

Tags: ruby, user-interface, ironruby, shoes

I found cool article on [Creating cross platform GUI's with IronRuby](http://iqueryable.com/2008/05/20/CreatingCrossPlatformGUIsWithIronRuby.aspx) where someone re-created the [Shoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoes_(GUI_toolkit) DSL by [_why the lucky stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff)  in IronRuby.

Awesome right!

So, I downloaded the [IronRuby binaries](http://www.ironruby.net/Download) and the [code from the article](http://iqueryable.com/ct.ashx?id=d593013f-15cb-462d-9d2e-5c0a5e10fd30&url=http%3a%2f%2fiqueryable.com%2fcontent%2fbinary%2fIronRubyDemos.zip) and ran the following command:

```
c:\IronRuby\bin\ir hello_world.rb
```

But I get the following error:

```
:0:in `require': no such file to load -- Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.2000 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (LoadError)
        from ./shoes.rb:5
        from hello_world.rb:1
        from :0:in `require'
```

How do I get these sample apps to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the version of MS.Scripting that it's asking for doesn't match the version you've got, that's a pretty common problem. Maybe check the version #s?

To check the version number, just right-click on `Microsoft.Scripting.dll` and you'll see the version #.

Comment: How do I check the version?  Can you elaborate a little?  Thanks!

Comment: Just right-click on Microsoft.Scripting.dll and see the version #

Comment: There are a few versions when you view the dll properties.  I found the "assembly" version to be correct.  I also had to set the Public Key Token - I was able to find this value in the ir.exe.config file.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make the 4 demos examples work after removing the following 5 lines from shoes.rb:

require 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.2000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
require 'IronRuby, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
include Microsoft::Scripting::Hosting
include Ruby::Runtime
include Ruby

These lines are not needed.